# Apache: disable directory listings

Tags: apache-2.2, security, .htaccess

I'm using Apache 2.2.

In the var/www directory I've created a .htaccess file that contains this:

```
Options -indexes
```

When I reach my site and want to see the directories and files like this:

www.myDomainName.com/static

I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /static/ on this server
```

GREAT!

But, when I type the concrete IP address of my site like this:

www.ipOfMyDomainName.com/static

I get:

```
Index of /static/
```

and I can see the whole directory structure and all the files.

How can I solve this? So nobody can see my files and directories.

---

UPDATE: So, I'm using virtual host and I had to delete "Indexes" from the file named "default" in the site-available directory

now it contains this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Probably not related, but shouldn't the I in indexes be capitalized? "Options -Indexes"

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing the same server?!

Comment: Yes, I'm accessing the same server. I've changed it to "I" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a way of changing the 403 to a 404 as well. I have a similar problem, but want to prevent the existence of a directory being detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing "Indexes" in this line in your httpd.conf.  If that doesn't work, try removing "All" too.

```
Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Comment: My httpd.conf file is an empty file.